# iText 7 - text overlay in a table, how to span over all possible columns

Tags: itext, cell, overlay, itext7

there is a picture visualizing my problem.

[image]

I have a table with let's say 5 columns and 5 rows. The first row and first column has a long text. The text won't fit in to the cell but I want to show the entire text in a line, spanning all the following columns. 
It is not a real colspan as the column-borders should still be visible. So it's more an overlay.

I am experimenting with the example "Fit text in cell" with the custom cell renderer but I don't really understand the different occupied areas, boxes and the dimensions coming with it.

Not to say that the dimension and positioning  thing in iText is not really intuitive.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this ?

[image]

C# example

```
//Create a table with 5 columns
var table = new Table(new float[] { 3,3,3,3,3}).SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100)).SetFixedLayout(); 
// Creat the cell with the long text
Cell cell = new Cell(1, 5).Add(new Paragraph("Long text that spans over the 5 Columns")); 
//Add the top row 5 cells    
table.AddCell("Column 1 text")
table.AddCell("Column 2 text")
table.AddCell("Column 3 text")
table.AddCell("Column 4 text")
table.AddCell("Column 5 text") 

//Add the long text
table.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Hi,

no, that is not what I want. That is easy, I know how to span. I want to keep the columns, I just need the text to be drawn over the following columns as you can see in my attached Image.

Comment: Ah so you want it to ignore the columns. And you want to keep those lines visibile ?

Comment: exact! ;) english is not mother tongue

Comment: it is more like a z-index, the first column contains the text but ignores the limit of the cell but not the limit of the table, reaching the end of the table means line break

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a built in feature from iText7. You could place a text in front of the table. But it will ignore the rules of the cell/table.

Comment: How would I do that? Placing a text in front of the table?

Comment: Absolute positioning is probably an option.

`Paragraph p = new Paragraph("test");`
`p.setFixedPosition(100, 800, 200);`
`document.add(p);`